# Extract substring inbetween quotation marks, but skip \" and turn it into " instead in Lua

Tags: regex, string, lua, match

I have this string

```lua
"argument \\\" \"some argument\" \"some argument with a quotation mark \\\" in here \""
```

which prints out as this

```
argument \" "some argument" "some argument with a quotation mark \" in here"
```

and I am trying to extract all of it, so that at the end it gets stored like this:

```
> [1] = "argument",
> [2] = """,
> [3] = "some argument",
> [4] = "some argument with a quotation mark " in here"
```

This is the code that I have so far.

```lua
function ExtractArgs(text)
    local skip = 0
    local arguments = {}
    local curString = ""

    for i = 1, text:len() do
        if (i <= skip) then continue end

        local c = text:sub(i, i)
        
        if (c == "\\") and (text:sub(i+1, i+1) == "\"") then
            continue
        end
        
        if (c == "\"") and (text:sub(i-1, i-1) ~= "\\") then
            local match = text:sub(i):match("%b\"\"")
            
            if (match) and (match:sub(#match-1,#match-1) ~= "\\") then
                curString = ""
                skip = i + #match
                arguments[#arguments + 1] = match:sub(2, -2)
            else
                curString = curString..c
            end
        elseif (c == " " and curString ~= "") then
            arguments[#arguments + 1] = curString
            curString = ""
        else
            if (c == " " and curString == "") then
                continue
            end

            curString = curString..c
        end
    end

    if (curString ~= "") then
        arguments[#arguments + 1] = curString
    end
    
    return arguments
end
```

```lua
print(ExtractArgs("argument \\\" \"some argument\" \"some argument with a quotation mark \\\" in here\""))
```

It extracts `\"` correctly that is not inbetween quotation marks, but not if it is inbetween quotation marks.

How can this be solved properly?

This seems to work with regex `\"([^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*)\"` but what about Lua?

Comment: Lua patterns do not support quantifying sequences so you won't be able to "translate" the regex to a Lua pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task cannot be done with a single Lua pattern but can be achieved with a chain of a few patterns.
The `text` parameter must not contain bytes `\0`, `\1` and `\2` - these special characters are used for temporary substitution.

```
local function ExtractArgs(text)
   local arguments = {}
   for argument in 
      ('""'..text:gsub("\\?.", {['\\"']="\1"}))
      :gsub('"(.-)"([^"]*)', function(q,n) return "\2"..q..n:gsub("%s+", "\0") end)
      :sub(2)
      :gmatch"%Z+" 
   do
      argument = argument:gsub("\1", '"'):gsub("\2", ""):gsub("\\(.)", "%1")
      print(argument)
      arguments[#arguments+1] = argument
   end   
   return arguments
end

ExtractArgs[[argument \"\\ "" "some argument" "some argument with a quotation mark \" in here \\"]]
```

Output:

```
argument
"\

some argument
some argument with a quotation mark " in here \
```

Comment: Is there something wrong if I changed it to this https://pastebin.com/3e3tJ4c9 ? Basically to allow \1 and \2 still to be used

Comment: Now you can use `"\2"` but cannot `"\\2"`

Comment: I guess at that point it can be modified further to even check for <name> to or something that the user wouldn't type, right?

Comment: I think I'll create another question. Maybe a better way on doing this. So that "\"" that prints out as """ gets extracted as "

Comment: I think the solution would profit more if you could comment each of the patterns to specify what each step does.

Comment: what is sub(2) used for?

Comment: `sub(2)` is needed to correctly parse `text = [[ arg]]`